# Several callbacks with if statements in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I implement if statements to model with several callbacks?

Something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :method1, if: :condition1
                :method2, if: :condition2
                :method3, if: :condition3

  ...

end
```

Adding comma after statement doesn't help.

Comment: Why not have one callback with all of the if statements in it?

Comment: I'm using some of these callbacks in `before_update`, `after_update` etc. So, I'll have to repeat them. It's not a DRY way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
before_create do
  callback1 if condition1
  callback2 if condition2
  callback3 if condition3
end
```